# How to stop Word from adding a blank line on a new page?

Tags: microsoft-word-2019

I am trying to find out if there is a possibility to stop Office Word 2019 from automatically adding a blank line on the next page.

This is the scenario:

- I have an image with caption that is followed by a text paragraph;
- The image's caption and text paragraph are separated by a blank line;
- If I place the image and caption on the bottom of a page, then the text paragraph will appear on the next page with a blank line before it (as expected).

I want for Word to automatically remove that blank line, because it is obvious that it is not needed since the text paragraph starts on a new page.

**Is it possible?**

Here is a screenshot that shows the scenario described above:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If the image is "small" no page break is added because of an extra line. So if the image is "larger", I just delete the superfluous line or two. Word cannot do this automatically so far as I know

Comment: Like @John mentioned, I either go to the end of the last line on the prior page and tap Delete, or while on the new page, tap Backspace.  The only time this won't work is if the prior page has columns at the bottom of the page.  Generally, Word only creates a line on a new page if that line has been forced down by content above it, or the content above it expands past the margins.

Comment: @JW0914 OK, so it is not possible. You can post your comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @CristianM John would actually be the one that provided the info, I just echoed what he said and elaborated a bit

Comment: @John You can post your comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: I did post an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is "small" no page break is added because of an extra line. So if the image is "larger", I just delete the superfluous line or two. Word cannot do this automatically so far as I know. This is how I do it in Word